# Can a GPL'ed WordPress plugin/theme incorporate an AGPL library?

Tags: gpl, gpl-2, agpl-3.0

If I develop a WordPress theme/plugin, and release it under a GPL license, can my plugin/theme incorporate (include) a third party library that is licensed under AGPL v.3?

If so, does my plugin/theme also need to be AGPL licensed? Or, just the changes (if any) I make to the third party library?

What about if I eventually commercialize the product (via paid support), are there any other important implications I should know about?

Generally speaking, I'm familiar with the implications of commercial WP plugins/themes and the GPL. I'm just wondering what (if any) further implications there are if the plugin/theme incorporates a third party AGPL library.

Edit: After posting this question, I found https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility . Just above the table it says "Each place that the matrix states GPLv3, the same statement about compatibility is true for AGPLv3 as well." so I assume I'm all clear but would love to hear confirmation. Thanks!